# fadeOut и fadeIn работают некорректно

Tags: javascript

Необходимо, чтобы сначала картинка пропадала, а затем появлялась новая. Сделал так:

```
srcs = [ "upload/discover.png", "upload/screenshot1.png", "upload/screenshot2.png", "upload/screenshot3.png", "upload/screenshot4.png" ]; 

window.onload = function(){ setInterval(function() 
{ 
    $('.image1').fadeOut(1200, function() { 
    $(this).attr('src',srcs[Math.floor(Math.random()*srcs.length)]).bind('onreadystatechange load', function() { 
    if (this.complete) $(this).fadeIn(1200); }); }); }, 3000); 
};
```

Однако при смене изображения с большого на маленькое то резко исчезает, а не плавно. [Вот как](http://uploads.ru/XB8Mx.gif)

Comment: может изображение огромное? и пока скачивается, проходит время интервала за минусом фейдов и поэтому дергается.

Comment: @Jean-Claude нет